# Angular Chart.js - Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, syntax-error

I am getting an error in the console when I open the page. It seems to be related to Chart.js 4.2.1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoJhJ.png).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2udyk.png).

Can this problem be on the side only Chart.js? Or how can I fix it?

I created a completely clean project and connected it there: "chart.js": "4.2.1","chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "2.2.0", "ng2-charts": "4.1.1". when opening the project the error was reproduced.

https://github.com/Fribolt/chartjs-issue.git - this empty project with reproduce this problem.

Comment: I don't know how your project is set up, but in a standard html + js project if one doesn't want to use modules, one has to link to the umd version of charts.js [chart.umd.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js)

Comment: I added link on project with reproduce this issue.

Comment: Have you tried one of the basic examples from the [ng2-charts site](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#BarChart)?

Comment: I found a problem, in the angular json file I indicated a link to the chart js node modle script, this caused an error in the console. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I found a problem, in the angular json file I indicated a link to the chart js node modle script, this caused an error in the console. thanks for the help!